# Recursive cycles and DFS

Tags: delphi, recursion, depth-first-search

I have a task to find all latin squares of size N with Depth-first search. I need to check all possible variants of squares size N whether they are latin. It can be done with N * N nested cycles 'for' from 1 to N (first cycle for the position(0,0), second nested for position (0,1) and so on). Obviously, it'll work only for some particular N₀. I need a more general solution, which could work for a random N, so I want to write a recursive procedure imitating these N * N cycles depending on N inputted.

Now I believe, I have a solution.

Comment: Have you ever written recursive functions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Comment: I've tried but the best attempt of mine skips possible squares.  I'll upload the code.

Comment: Why did you remove the code? Was it the solution?

Comment: If it's about the code in my question, it does not work properly. If it's about the code in my answer, I've changed it two times to work faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems working. Hope someone'll find it useful.

Upd: removed useless 1-dimensional array, seems to work faster now (as I calculated (but not checked experimentally), the previous way would take ≈218.07 hours for N=4).

Upd2: moved from using flag and 'if' in LS check to label, seems even faster(271.172 seconds average of two experiments to find LS of size 4(checks 4294967296 variants) vs 4041.453 seconds for the previous update).

```
procedure filling(str, col: Integer);
var
I, I1, J1, a, b, fl: Integer;
label
skip;

begin
 for I := 1 to N do begin
  lat_sq[str, col]:=I;
  if (col<N-1) then filling(str, col+1)
   else if  (str<N-1) then filling(str+1, 0)
  else if (str=N-1) and (col=N-1) then begin
  

   
   for I1 := 0 to N-1 do
    for J1 := 0 to N-1 do begin

      for a := 0 to N-1 do
       if (a<>I1) and (lat_sq[I1, J1]=lat_sq[a, J1]) then goto skip; 
      for b := 0 to N-1 do
       if (b<>J1) and (lat_sq[I1, J1]=lat_sq[I1, b]) then goto skip; 
    end;

   
    for I1 := 0 to N-1 do begin
     for J1 := 0 to N-1 do
     write(lat_sq[I1, J1]);
     writeln;
    end;

    writeln;

  
   skip:
  end;
 end;

end;
```

upd3: decided to keep previous code as this new has another method of LS checking: if it's not possible to fill the cell examined, it moves to another cycle for I iteration. Finds LSs for N=4 for less then 1 millisecond, found for N=6 for 1468.687 seconds, higher N require senseless time. N_1 means N-1.

upd4: removed useless additional check in if, found LSs for N=6 for 1410.719 seconds.

```
procedure filling(str, col: Integer);
var
I, I1, J1, a, b, fl: Integer;
label
skip;

begin
 for I := 1 to N do begin

  lat_sq[str, col]:=I;

  fl:=1;

  for I1 := 0 to str-1 do
   if (lat_sq[I1, col]=lat_sq[str, col]) then goto skip;

  for J1 := 0 to col-1 do
   if (lat_sq[str, J1]=lat_sq[str, col]) then  goto skip; 



  if (col<n_1) then filling(str, col+1)
   else if (str<n_1) then filling(str+1, 0)




   else begin
    
    for I1 := 0 to N-1 do begin
     for J1 := 0 to N-1 do
     write(lat_sq[I1, J1]);
     writeln;
    end;

    writeln;
    

    inc(count);

   end; 
  skip:
 end;

end;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a permutation generator, like Heap's alghorithm:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heaps-algorithm-for-generating-permutations/

Start each row with 1, 2, ..., N.

For i = to N
Take a permutation of row i, and check there are no repetitions in
any column.  I there are, take the next permutation of this row.
If there are no repetitions, just take the next row (next i).

Comment: I've tried earlier to find all permutations of N elements and all k-permutations of n! strings I got but for 3x3 squares this way allowed to find only a half of LSs.